# my webpage navigation starts to flow into more rows when I make my window smaller

Tags: html, css

I am new to all of this so How do I make everything where it is no matter how much smaller I make the window?

Comment: please show relevant code otherwise its pretty hard rather impossible to answer your question since its vague ..

Answer (score 0):

Start coding width and height using percentages % like

```
width:100% or Height="45%"
```

this will render the size according to the window size

Comment: Yea i thought that too and set my width long before asking this question. I am not sure why if i have that set that my webpage navigation starts to flow into more rows anyway.. What am i missing maybe?

Comment: u really need to play with width and height for all the browser compatibility

Comment: I don't mean to argue but I am working with sizes but nothing is staying put... is there a certain order of things? is there is anything with width that I need that maybe I don't know? thanks for responding!